# Comma Separated Values in SQL using Stored PRocedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

What i currently have is:

```
COUNT DETAILS:
CNT DTLID      COUNT           TOTAL QTY        UNITPRICE            AMOUNT
1              234                 2222           1.20                 32
1              12                   123           2                     21


What i want it to be like
CNT DTLID      COUNT           TOTAL QTY         UNITPRICE            AMOUNT
1              234,12          2222 , 123        1.20,2               32 + 21 = 53
```

I want to have comma Separated values and also want to use group by clause for amount column.

Currently What I`m upto is:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Tbl_CountDetail_SelectAll]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.

    select * from Tbl_CountDetail 
    inner join tbl_Contract
    on
    tbl_CountDetail.ContractID = tbl_Contract.ContractID
    inner join tbl_Count
    on
    tbl_CountDetail.CountID = tbl_Count.CountID
    where tbl_CountDetail.isDeleted = 0
    and tbl_Contract.isdeleted = 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Some friendly sample data

```
create table #CountDetails
(
DTLID int,
CNT int,
Qty int,
UnitPrice money,
Amount int
)

insert into #CountDetails
SELECT
1, 234, 2222, 1.20, 32
UNION ALL SELECT
1, 12, 123, 2, 21
```

Here's some code

```
SELECT 
    DTLIDs.DTLID,

    CNTs =
        ISNULL(
            STUFF(
                (
                    select ',' + 
                        cast(CD.cnt as varchar(50))
                    from #CountDetails CD
                    where CD.DTLID = DTLIDs.DTLID
                    order by CD.CNT
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ),
                1, 1, ''  --removes the leading ','
            ),
            ''
        ),

    QTYs =
        ISNULL(
            STUFF(
                (
                    select ',' + 
                        cast(CD.qty as varchar(50))
                    from #CountDetails CD
                    where CD.DTLID = DTLIDs.DTLID
                    order by CD.Qty
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ),
                1, 1, ''  --removes the leading ','
            ),
            ''
        ),

    UnitPrices =
        ISNULL(
            STUFF(
                (
                    select ',' + 
                        cast(CD.UnitPrice as varchar(50))
                    from #CountDetails CD
                    where CD.DTLID = DTLIDs.DTLID
                    order by CD.UnitPrice
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ),
                1, 1, ''  --removes the leading ','
            ),
            ''
        ),

    AmountSum =
    (
        select SUM(Amount) from #CountDetails CD
        where CD.DTLID = DTLIDs.DTLID
    )

from (
    select distinct DTLID from #CountDetails
    ) DTLIDs
```

There are various ways to tweak this.  For example, the "AmountSum =" nested query code be done on a group by  - I just like the more consistent look given the way the rest of the query is structured.

For the CSV lists, you didn't specify how you wanted it sorted.  I've ordered by the values  (eg ORDER BY CD.CNT) but you can change that to order by whatever you want.  Similarly there are no spaces between the CSV values.  You can tweak this by changing the select ',' to have a space in there and parameters to the STUFF command (change the second 1 to a 2).

Basically the FOR XML PATH('') bit takes the mini resultset its given and returns some text with no XML literals (due to the '').  This is tidied up using STUFF to remove the leading , at the start of the XML PATH result.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The select statement you've given doesn't seem to correspond to the sample data you provided.  I've ignored your query when doing my answer...  Please retrofit to suit.

Comment: is this the stored procedure or a function?
do i have to write a function for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done something like this....

```
DECLARE @VALUES NVARCHAR(1000),@UnitPrice nvarchar(100)
SELECT @VALUES = COALESCE(@VALUES + ',','') + CAST(COUNTQty AS NVARCHAR(50)),
@UnitPrice = COALESCE(@UnitPrice + ',','') + CAST(UnitPrice AS NVARCHAR(50)) FROM tableName
SELECT @VALUES as [CountQty],@Ids as [UnitPrice]
```

Have not checked group by price issue..!!